# How do I grayscale an MPO stereographic image file from a 3D camera? I want to use it as input for a CNC carvings

Tags: file-format, 3d

I had/have a 3D camera back in the day, and got a few 3D pictures. I kinda stopped using it since there wasn't anything I could do with the MPO (Multi Picture Object) files. However, the 3D camera might gain a new life if I can turn the pictures into a CNC (Computer Number Control) carving by grayscaling the MPO files. Does anyone know if this is possible and how it could be done?

BTW, I wasn't sure if this is the right subgroup to ask this to. If it isn't, then please kindly direct me to the sub group I should ask such a question to. I asked on the engineering side, but they directed me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. MPO files are basically just a [stereogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscopy), like the old ViewMaster stereo image viewers. Different portions of the images presented to the left and right eyes are shifted laterally to give the illusion of 3D depth. What you'd like to do is reverse-engineer the 3D depth map from the stereogram pair. Given a depth map, it's a short step to creating 3D prints (which is beyond the scope of this site).

A couple of resources to get you further:

- [From Stereo Pair to Lenticular Print](https://triaxes.com/articles/from-stereo-pair-to-lenticular-print/) describes using Stereo Tracer Pro by Triaxes to create a depth map.
- There is at least one service, [depthmask.com](https://depthmask.com), that apparently does this for you after uploading an MPO file.

Once you have a depth map, there are solutions to use it to create the appropriate file for bas relief or CNC carving.

I suggest searching for subjects such as "bas relief 3D print from depth map" or "lithogram 3D print from stereogram". The solution is out there, but will certainly require some time and sweat to put together a solution if you don't want to pay for depth map creation solutions per image.

Comment: While the programs you listed isn't 100% there. It's a lot closer than I was. Like they aren't good for detail. But I don't think I could make a better program if had to.